# go-redis v8 XAutoClaim incompatible with Redis server v7+

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

#### Issue

I am using go-redis v8 against a redis v7 server instance. From what I can tell there is an incompatibility in the `XAutoClaim` command.
`client.XAutoClaim` returns error: `got 3, wanted 2`.

The official [go-redis/v8 docs on XAutoClaim](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#Client.XAutoClaim) do not mention an incompatibility with redis version 7+.

#### Steps to reproduce

```
        ctx := context.Background()

        streamName := "test-stream"
        groupName := "test-group"

        rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
            Addr:     "localhost:6379",
            Password: "", // no password set
            DB:       0,  // use default DB
        })
        defer rdb.FlushDB(ctx).Err()

        // Add message to stream
        rdb.XAdd(ctx, &redis.XAddArgs{
            Stream: streamName,
            Values: map[string]interface{}{"key": "value"},
        })

        // Create consumer group
        rdb.XGroupCreateMkStream(ctx, streamName, groupName, "0")

        autoclaimError := rdb.XAutoClaim(ctx, &redis.XAutoClaimArgs{
            Stream:       streamName,
            Group:        groupName,
            Consumer:     "test-consumer",
            MinIdle:      0,
            Start:        "-",
            Count:        1,
        }).Err()
        print(autoclaimError.Error())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go-redis v8 XAutoClaim is incompatible with Redis version 7+. While this issue is not officially documented, there is an issue on the matter here: https://github.com/redis/go-redis/issues/2106.